# Adding multiple table rows dynamically

Tags: java, row, vaadin

I have a Vaadin table and I want to **add rows dynamically** in it.

The code I have tried works fine and when I click the add row button a new row appears in the table. The problem is that when I click the button for the second, third etc. time, no new row is appeared in the table. I would like to add as many rows as the button is clicked. How can I nail it?

Below is the code where the table is created:

```
    public Table createTable(BeanContainer beans) {

    table.setContainerDataSource(beans);
    table.setColumnHeader("PS_SECTION", "ID");
    table.setColumnHeader("NAME", "SECTION");
    table.setColumnHeader("VORDER","ORDER");

    table.addGeneratedColumn("ACTIVE", new Table.ColumnGenerator() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public Object generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId,
                Object columnId) {

            final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("");
            Set<Object> keys = itemIdToCheckbox.keySet();

                for (Object key : keys) {                       
                        PS_SECTION PS = (PS_SECTION) sectionMap.get(key);

                        if (PS.getISACTIVE() == 1) { 
                            CheckIt(key,true);                              
                        }
                        else if(PS.getISACTIVE() == 0){ 
                            CheckIt(key,false);                         
                        }                               
                }

            checkBox.addAttachListener(new AttachListener() {
                @Override
                public void attach(AttachEvent event) { 
                    itemIdToCheckbox.put(itemId, checkBox);
                    tableToCheck.put(itemId, checkBox);                                                         
                }
            });

            checkBox.addDetachListener(new DetachListener() {
                @Override
                public void detach(DetachEvent event) {
                    itemIdToCheckbox.remove(itemId);
                    tableToCheck.remove(itemId);
                }
            });

            checkBox.addValueChangeListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {                    
                @Override
                public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {                      
                    Boolean selected = (Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue();                                                                        
                }
            });

            return checkBox;                
        }               
    });   

    table.setMultiSelect(false);
    table.setVisibleColumns(new Object[]{"PS_SECTION", "NAME", "VORDER", "ACTIVE"});
    table.setEditable(true);
    table.setSelectable(true);
    table.setImmediate(true); 
    table.commit();
    return table;
}
```

And here is the container code:

```
    public BeanContainer createContainer() {                   
       beans.setBeanIdProperty("PS_SECTION");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            PS_SECTION section = list.get(i);

                Long ps =  section.getPS_SECTION();
                String na = section.getNAME();
                Long is = section.getISACTIVE();
                Long isg = section.getISGLOBAL();
                Long or = section.getVORDER();
                Integer st = section.getSTATUS();

             beanlist.add(new PS_SECTION(ps, na, is, isg, or, st));       
        }           
        beans.addAll(beanlist);  
    return beans;
}
```

Finally, the Row Add Button code:

```
addButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {                                     
                 Object newbean = beans.addBean(new PS_SECTION(0L, null, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0));   
                 table.addItem(newbean);
        }
    });
```

Also tried the following to avoid duplicates. Same thing happened

```
                    long in = 200;
                    Object newbean = beans.addBean(new PS_SECTION(in, null, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0));    
                    ++in;
                    table.addItem(newbean);
```

Comment: What is the identifier of the newBean ? Probably you have duplicates...)

Comment: @AndréSchild The identifier is the first long from the beans. I edited my question now, according to your comment. Same thing happened. What do you think should I do?

Comment: Try calling the table.refreshRowCache(); method after you've added your items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep this line: 
`long in = 200;`
outside of the add button clicklistener code. Maybe you can make it global (class) member;

Comment: Keeping the line outside of the add button sure helped. Thanks!